# Android NDK: compile HDF5 library with source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, hdf5

Now I have a 3rd party library (HDF5)in source code. But this library is written in C++. Is it possible to use android NDK to compile it? How? Do I need to write own makefile to configure it OR use android.mk to configure? 
And I found this library has some dependencies, Do I need to compile each one of them?

Comment: I'm also working on the same thing, let me know if you've found a way please

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is easier to use the standard `.lconfigure && make` for external native libraries, but you need to prepare a *standalone toolchain*, as described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html).

Comment: Thank you, @CameronLowellPalmer. I updated the link, now *finally* Google has NDK documents on the official Android developers site, I hope it will be maintained better.

Answer (score 0):

A short answer to your question is, yes, it can be build with NDK and autotools.

Comment: I am quite  confuse steps after 5. All I need is a compiled library either in shared or static type. How do I get these?

Comment: This is a dead link - does this information exist anywhere?

Comment: @troy.unrau I second that, I would very much like to know as well